# Adding navigational buttons to the Outlook CRM 2011 ribbon

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am currently using the Visual Ribbon Editor for CRM 2011 and i am trying to add a button to the Outlook client ribbon (not the web client) that loads the Accounts section of CRM (not in a modal, but the how it would normally load accounts in the main pane) The tabbed section in Outlook is shown in the image below.

I do not have to use the editor, and could use a solution, but i am unsure what sort of command i would need to get it to update the main pane and with either the visual tool or the by hand solution.

[image: Accounts Tabbed interface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the HomePageGrid ribbon XML. 
Gareth Tucker has written a great tutorial to add a button to the Form ribbon 
 (just modify where it says Mscrm.Form to Mscrm.HomePageGrid): 
http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/01/18/how-to-view-ribbon-definitions-in-crm-2011-3/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's on topic so feel free to trash it. I won't be sad.

There's a fantastic tool called [Ribbon Workbech](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx). They even got a video showing how to do stuff, which is perfect for a complicated software in combination with lazy... hrmp... busy people.

There's even more info [over here](http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/71374-1-getting-started-with-the-ribbon-workbench). Have a look.